# How to translate an inner enum into idiomatic Julia code?

Tags: enums, julia

I'm trying to [translate](https://github.com/rburing/godot-julia) some C++ game engine code into Julia. There is an `Object` class with a `void free()` method, and a `Node` class inheriting from `Object` which has a `void queue_free()` method. I've translated this into Julia as follows:

```
abstract type GameEngineObject end

struct Object <: GameEngineObject
    native_ptr::Ptr{Nothing}
end

function free(self::GameEngineObject)
    # something with self.native_ptr
end

abstract type GameEngineNode <: GameEngineObject end

struct Node <: GameEngineNode
    native_ptr::Ptr{Nothing}
end

function queue_free(self::GameEngineNode)
    # something with self.native_ptr
end
```

So far so good. This setup allows me to call `Object`'s methods on instances of `Node`. Now, the original C++ `Node` class contains an `enum ProcessMode { PROCESS_MODE_INHERIT = 0, PROCESS_MODE_PAUSABLE = 1, PROCESS_MODE_WHEN_PAUSED = 2, PROCESS_MODE_ALWAYS = 3, PROCESS_MODE_DISABLED = 4 }` and a method `ProcessMode get_process_mode()`.

My question is: What is a *Julian* way to translate such an *inner* `enum` into Julia code?

One way to go is to break out the `enum` completely, and add prefixes to avoid name clashes:

```
@enum NodeProcessMode begin
    NODE_PROCESS_MODE_INHERIT = 0
    NODE_PROCESS_MODE_PAUSABLE = 1
    NODE_PROCESS_MODE_WHEN_PAUSED = 2
    NODE_PROCESS_MODE_ALWAYS = 3
    NODE_PROCESS_MODE_DISABLED = 4
end
```

Is there any cleaner way? I'm looking for something systematic, as I'm generating these Julia bindings by code. It would be nice to be able to refer to the enum as `Node.ProcessMode` in Julia, but I think this would require `Node` to be a Julia module, and then I'm not sure how to organize the `abstract type`s and the `struct`s in a good way, while keeping a clean API. Maybe the module can be made callable? Or is breaking the enum out as above just the cleanest option?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C++ so from what I could look up, you're looking for enums in a class's scope. Your understanding that `module`s are the namespace structure is good, but that's entirely separated from types so there's no way to combine them into a dispatchable module-type.

```
# isolate from other global scopes
module _ProcessMode # name in its own scope so can't be same as enum's
  # makes some const globals
  @enum ProcessMode begin
    PROCESS_MODE_INHERIT = 0
    PROCESS_MODE_PAUSABLE = 1
    PROCESS_MODE_WHEN_PAUSED = 2
    PROCESS_MODE_ALWAYS = 3
    PROCESS_MODE_DISABLED = 4
  end
end
```

That said, you *can* use a method to associate any object with a type. I wouldn't say this is Julian because I haven't see this done in practice (enums are rare as is):

```
processmode(::Type{Node}) = _ProcessMode.ProcessMode
# processmode(Node) gets the enum's type

function Base.getproperty(::Type{Node}, name::Symbol)
  if name == :ProcessMode
    _ProcessMode.ProcessMode
  end
end
# Node.ProcessMode gets the enum's type too, much less idiomatic
```

I don't know what your C++ code looks like, but getting the enum like that doesn't seem very useful because you can't get at the instances like `ProcessMode::PROCESS_MODE_INHERIT`. The enum instances are assigned to `const` global variables in the module so you could associate that instead:

```
processmode(::Type{Node}) = _ProcessMode
# processmode(Node) gets the module
# processmode(Node).PROCESS_MODE_INHERIT gets an instance
```

From what I could tell in C++ examples, you can avoid typing out the class and enum type and just use the instance's name in class methods. You could do that in Julia by defining methods in the enum's module, just import the types and functions first.

```
# ...Node-related types...
function foo end # assume in same global scope as `Node`

module _ProcessMode
  import .Main: Node, foo # replace Main with where `Node` and `foo` is
  # ...enum from before...
  foo(::Node) = PROCESS_MODE_ALWAYS
end
# foo(Node(...))
```

All that said, this isn't very idiomatic, but there may be a degree of that when translating code. For more ideas, a package EnumX.jl has `@enumx` for an implementation of scoped enums, using modules.